# How can I change the shape of the flutter showAboutDialog?

Tags: flutter

I'm calling the [showAboutDialog](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showAboutDialog.html) as following:

```
onTap: () {
    showAboutDialog(
            context: context,
            applicationName: SettingsScreen.nameToDisplay,
            applicationLegalese: formatDateAppLegalese.format(DateTime.now()),
            applicationVersion: SettingsScreen.versionToDisplay,
            children: aboutBoxChildren,
        );
},
```

How can I change the shape of that dialog? I know how to style and alert dialog and add for example rounded corners but this is not transferable to the case of the `showAboutDialog` in flutter.

Adding corners to the `children` attribute does not have the right effect.

Is there a way to change the shape of that dialog and if how?

Comment: I need this too :/ 
I want to edit a lot of things on it.. like show the Scrollbar

Answer (score 2):

Considering this code:

```
onTap: () {
 showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) {
      return AboutDialog(
        applicationVersion: "1.0.2",
        applicationName: "Flutter app",
      );
    },
  );
},
```

You should modify your app theme to change the shape of your AboutDialog like this:

```
dialogBackgroundColor: Colors.grey,
dialogTheme: DialogTheme(
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
  ),
  elevation: 5,
),
```

Comment: In fact, you don't need to modify the onTap: code !

Comment: Yeah, let me edit the answer ! ~ Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can change the topic of only a certain dialog (or group of dialogs):

```dart
Theme(
  data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
    dialogTheme: DialogTheme(
      shape: ...,
      backgroundColor: ...,
      alignment: ...,
    ),
  ),
  child: AboutDialog( // or any other dialog
    applicationName: ...,
    applicationVersion: ...,
    applicationIcon: ...,
    applicationLegalese: ...,
    children: ...,
  ),
);
```